# Azure Deploy Web App Error with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, azure, azure-web-app-service

We've previously been able to deploy our Java web application through Eclipse to Azure with no issues, but recently today we kept receiving an error message that says

```
FTP client can't store the artifact, reply code: 550
```

Anybody know what Azure is trying to say here ?  Why would it suddenly start giving a 550 error?  Deploying to a different Azure web application works fine, just can't seem to deploy to the same one as before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 550 error code of FTP on IIS normally means deny access or no permission to do some operation. Please try these ways as below.

1. Restart your Azure WebApp on Azure portal.
2. Reconfigure the deployment credentials with new username and password on Azure portal.
3. [Remote Administration of Windows Azure Websites using IIS Manager](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/remote-administration-of-windows-azure-websites-using-iis-manager/) to check the configuration for FTP. For example, there is a similar thread from SuperUser https://superuser.com/questions/845357/iis-ftp-folder-access-issues-550 which you can refer to.

Hope it helps.

Comment: 1. Restart your Azure WebApp on Azure portal. worked for me

Answer (score 1):

The issue can also be caused if there is no webapps folder. Assure that path exists:

> /site/wwwroot/webapps/